# Is there any approach to get the JWT token from the Amazon Cognito using API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-cognito

I am trying to get **JWT authorization** tokens from the **Amazon Cognito** for a user. I have to get the token via the server which is built in java code.

I want to work like this:

- Hit Amazon Cognito with user credentials
- Authorize the user and return the JWT token

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best example you can find at the moment: https://blog.kdgregory.com/2016/12/server-side-authentication-with-amazon.html